# Notification error into Thread

Tags: android, android-notifications

I created an app using Threads.
In thread I have a procudere to send a notification, but it is not working.
Where am I wrong?

Code:

```
 NotificationManager notificationManager;   
    Notification myNotification;   
    private final String myBlog = "http://www.example.com/";  
    private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID=1;  


   @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
        setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);   

 userFunctions = new UserFunctions();   

  inputUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginUsername);   
        btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);   
       inputThread = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.thread_modified_text);   
       SharedPreferences userDetails = getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);  
        username = userDetails.getString("username", "");   
        inputUsername.setText(username);    

 currentThread = new Thread(this);   
            currentThread.start();

}

    @Override  
    public void run() {    
        try {   
                   while(username != null)  
                    {  
            Thread.sleep(5000);  
            threadHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);         
                    }                                     
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {  
            //    
        }  
    }

private Handler threadHandler = new Handler() 
{

public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {

   myNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.stat_notify_chat,   
                    "A new notificatin!",   
                    System.currentTimeMillis());    
     Context context = getApplicationContext();    
     String notificationTitle = "Notification";    
     String notificationText = "XXXX";    
     Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myBlog));    
     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(),     
                                   0, myIntent,    
                                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);    
      myNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;    
      myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;   
      myNotification.setLatestEventInfo(context,    
                                  notificationTitle,    
                                  notificationText,    
                                  pendingIntent);    
      notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);    

}
}
```

Comment: It is not working.? What it means. did you got any error.?

Comment: my app crashes.. "unfortunately has stopped etc"

Comment: So, will you mind posting your log cat stacktrace.?

Comment: sorry, I missed notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); Now, my app does't crash but it don't show notification. If I use AlarmDialog, it's all right.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write Looper.prepare() in run() method of your thread.This worked for me..
Hope this helps.